# knockout send value from input to function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a text box and a button and I want to send the value from the textbox to a function when the button is clicked cant seem to figure it out.

```
      Reg:<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reg" data-bind="text: search"  />
<button  class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: function () { GJobs(search) }" >Get Jobs</button>
```

function in the view model

```
   self.GJobs = function (search) {
        GetJobs(search)
    }
```

ajax call

```
   function GetJobs(search) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'api/mechanicphone',
            data: { reg: search},
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                self.Jobs(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#MechMobile').html('<h3>Error in retrieval</h3>');
            }
        });
    }
```

the reg passed is coming null on the get when  i debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things that should be changed in your code.

First, in order to return value from the input field the `value` binding should be used instead of `text:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reg" data-bind="value: search"  />
```

Then your click handler ideally should call function in your view model, which then can get the value of observable variable `search`. Overall you can update your HTML code like this:

```
Reg:<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reg" data-bind="value: search"  />
<button  class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: GJobs" >Get Jobs</button>
```

And your view model like this:

```
self.GJobs = function () {
    GetJobs(self.search());
}
self.search = ko.observable('');
function GetJobs(searchValue){
    // Call web service
}
```